# Logout all open tabs automatically when user logs out in one of the opened tabs in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, tabs

I am working on php session concept in php. created login page using jquery and php and created sessions for all pages when i logged in session runs i can open logged in urls in another tabs to which works great but i have an issue in logout.

when i logout in one of the opened browser tab other tabs still it runs manually if i refresh pages gets logged out. My requirement is when i logout in one of the tab other tabs should automatically logout instead of manually.

**DB file**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","testing") or die ("Oops! Server not connected"); // Connect to the host

?>
```

**Login.php**

```
   <?php
    include 'db.php';
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] != '')
    { // Redirect to secured user page if user logged in

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "userpage.php"; </script>';
    }
?>
<html>

    <body>
        <form>
            <table class="mytable">
                <tr>
                    <td>Username</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="as_input" value="s"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="as_input" value="s"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" class="as_button" value="Login &raquo;" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

**welcome home page**

```
<?php
    include 'db.php';
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || $_SESSION['username'] == '')
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "login.php"; </script>';
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="as_wrapper">

            <h2>
                welcome to home page
            </h2>
            <a href="logout.php" class="a">logout</a><br><br>
            <a href='#'>test link</a>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
    include 'library.php';
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    unset($_SESSION['password']);
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "login.php"; </script>';

?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513874/logout-all-open-tabs-automatically-when-user-logs-out-in-one-of-them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logout all open tabs automatically when user logs out in one of them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513874/logout-all-open-tabs-automatically-when-user-logs-out-in-one-of-them)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a php page:

checkStatus.php

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] != '')
        echo true;

    else 
        echo false;
?>
```

Now in every page have this jQuery code:

```
var _delay = 3000;
function checkLoginStatus(){
     $.get("checkStatus.php", function(data){
        if(!data) {
            window.location = "logout.php"; 
        }
        setTimeout(function(){  checkLoginStatus(); }, _delay); 
        });
}
checkLoginStatus();
```

So every page after certain ammount of delay will call a js function repeatatively a which will check the login status by making an ajax call to a php file (you have created). If the user is logged out from any it will destroy the session in the browser and make all the tabs to redirect to the logout.php page.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a javascript listener that checks if the session has been destroyed;

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  /// call your function here to cechk the server
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ajax](http://jquery.com/download/) to check if the **user's session** is still set.
You should make a call to the bellow js function after you have included [ajax](http://jquery.com/download/)

```
var targetURL="login.php";

  function auto_check_login(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "check_user_session.php",
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
          if(data != 1){
              window.location=targetURL; //Redirect user to login page.
          }
      } 
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){

    auto_check_login(); //Call auto_check_login function when DOM is Ready

  });

  //Call auto_check_login after 2 seconds
  setInterval(auto_check_login,2000);
```

Then in **check_user_session.php** file, you can have this

```
session_start();

if( !isset($_SESSION['username']) || !isset($_SESSION['password']) ){
print 0;
} else {
print 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if $_SESSION['username'] is set not just one time, but many times. 
Check if this index exists and, if not, redirect the user to the login page.