# Logout Opened pages in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logout

I have an mvc web application, when the user open the pages in different tabs an click the logout button in a particular page, it will logout all the open related pages. I tried to logout and redirect to login but only on that page only.

how can i logout all opened pages in the other tabs when the user click on the logout button in a particular page.

thank you.

Comment: what is the mechanism that your following for logout? expire the session? or clear cookies that are created? update in the post

Comment: i have set an idle time to logout. it will clear the session and cookies.

Comment: You can try polling with ajax or WebSocket e.g. with `SignalR` to update the authentication status in real time. But it is too much work and overhead IMO.

Comment: your planning to make this logout mechanism using your C# controller code or anything else?

Comment: yes in c#, particularly in controller. i want to logout all open pages if user click the logout button.

Comment: BTW, you are already logged out (if you use standard MVC authentication). It's just the page refresh. You should not be able to access any internal page methods anymore, so actions will fail. I will go by Hendry proposal: Search SignalR examples. It lets you have a bidirectional one-to-many communication between your website and the pages you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up server-side and client-side code. Your C# code cannot access user's browser - so you won't be able to logout other tabs this way.

If you are using cookie to store the authentication info you could add a javascript function that checks this cookie in a loop, but I don't think this is a good idea (performance-wise, unnecessary load etc.). Checking the appropriate permissions on your Controllers should be more than enough.

You could also use html5 local storage and event, [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513874/logout-all-open-tabs-automatically-when-user-logs-out-in-one-of-them).