# logout user from all active tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, authentication, logout

I have three instances of my application open in three separate tabs, user logs out from one tab, and in the same tab logs in with another credentials, and start browsing with one of the two other tabs, How can I logout user from those two tabs?

My front end technology is AngularJS, APIs are written in Web Api, I use token for authentication, token is stored inside a session cookie.

Comment: Have a look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513874/logout-all-open-tabs-automatically-when-user-logs-out-in-one-of-them) question.

Comment: @JeroenHeier I don't use local storage, token is stored in cookie

Comment: @JeroenHeier I want to log out user when he closes his browser too, which is not possible with localstorage, and sessionStorage is not suitable either because if user logs in, in a tab, I want him to be logged in other tabs too.

Answer (score 0):

when user logouts from one tab you can send a request to server to disable/destroy the token.

In your web API you can check if token is valid, if it is not you can return unauthorized status code.

```
if (!IsValidToken())
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,ErrorMessage);
```

and use interceptors to redirect user to your login page when you recieve unauthorised status from server.

```
.factory('myInterceptor', ['$q', '$location', '$injector', function ($q, $location, $injector) {
    return {
        response: function (response) {
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        responseError: function (rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 401) {
                var stateService = $injector.get('$state');
                stateService.go('login');
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    }
}])
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
}]);
```

with this method users would be redirected to login only if they do further requests from those others tabs. If you want them to be redirected without doing any request you can use $interval to check validity of the token every few seconds.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I don't want to use `$interval` as much as I can, I like a more deterministic approach ...

Answer (score -2):

When user clicks on logout, the following script works

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header("Location: ../index.php");
exit();
}
```

It automatically destroys the session from all tabs. When user Login with other credentials in one tab, he is still able to access the same page in other tabs because the session is still on with his credentials on the page.

Comment: My login is handled by a token which is stored inside a cookie, it is REST and also the back-end is Web API